# strip whitespace except spaces

Tags: python, whitespace, fasta

I find myself with a unique problem. I need to parse a file in which I need to put all of the lines into one string, with which I generally approach with str.strip() however I have realized that there are spaces at the beginning and end of each line which have important value. Is there an easy way to strip all whitespace except spaces? If not, what's a good way to delete specific characters from my strings since an alternate approach would be to do this for all the types of whitespace that appear.

Here's the file in question.
http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/ss.txt

Comment: please post an example of the file

Comment: This is locale-dependent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
whitespace = "\r\n\t"
my_string.strip(whitespace)
```

Or, using the `string` module:

```
import string
whitespace_except_space = string.whitespace.replace(" ", "")
my_string.strip(whitespace_except_space)
```

Comment: This assumes that the white space in the middle is not explicitly a space. The question does not specify that. @avorum needs to specify if there are spaces as well as tab characters in the middle. If not, your answer is correct. Otherwise there is still a problem. The comment seems to strip out leading spaces when I tried to show it.

Comment: You can remove the tabs from the `whitespace` variable and then you should be fine.

Comment: I meant that if explicit spaces are in the middle and at the end, that might cause a problem in giving the solution. For example '\ta\t\tb\t\tc\t\td\t' how do you remove from the middle but not from the end.?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a unix utility:
    `tr -d '\n' < seq.fa`
Just use the option -d 'whitespace-element' that you want to remove.